# how to select random effects in a GLMM?

Tags: glmm

I have data from a group of subjects (n=7) performing a two-alternative forced-choice task, where they can respond left or right.
The number of trials depends on the subject in the range of 1000 to 2000 trials per subject.

I want to model the response as a logistic regression depending on several variables:  y ~ a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>x<sub>3</sub>

So far my approach was to fit a glm for each subject and then calculate a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> as the mean of the values obtained.
I think this approach is correct if the number of trials for each subject is large enough so the values that I obtain for each subject are accurate.

The value of a0 (bias left-right) was very idiosyncratic for each subject, but I am not really interested in it.
The values of a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> are similar for all the subjects although they have certain variability across subjects.
I am interested in the mean values for the population of these sensitivities.

Now I am performing more experiments where I won't have so many trials for each subject. I won't be able to use the previous approach, I think I should fit a generalized mixed model using the subjects as random effects.

But I don't know how to select the random effects,

Is ok to fit a glmm just adding random effects for the intercept?      `+ (1 | subject)`
Or should I include random effects for all the slopes?      `+ (1 | subject) + (a1 | subject) + (a2 | subject) + (a3 | subject)`

Comment: are you still only going to have 7 subjects?

Comment: No, I plan to increase the number of subjects but I am not sure how many trials I will be able to get from the new subjects.